# Component with <ng-content>

Tags: angular

I've seen working examples when `<ng-content>` is beeing used inside other nested components (like [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hn393B9fJN6zgfaz54tn)) but I haven't managed to run it inside a root Angular2 component:

HTML template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <app>
            <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        </app>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Angular 2 component in TypeScript:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})
@View({
    template: 'Header: <ng-content></ng-content>',
})
export class App {
}

bootstrap(App);
```

I'd expect that this will generate:

```
<app>
    Header: <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</app>
```

but it doesn't and the content of `<app>` is ignored. See demo on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dJlA4SQpy8pnrdyDiy9u).

I thought maybe this goes against some Angular 2 philosophy or something so it's not even supported, but my use case is very similar to the first [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hn393B9fJN6zgfaz54tn) I think.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you run your example, did you notice how `Hello World!` is displayed during loading?

Basically, the HTML between `<app>` and `</app>` is used to display something while Angular is booting up.

Also, from the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/platform/browser.ts#L55):

> An application is bootstrapped inside an existing browser DOM, typically `index.html`. Unlike Angular 1, Angular 2 does not compile/process bindings in `index.html`. This is mainly for security reasons, as well as architectural changes in Angular 2. This means that `index.html` can safely be processed using server-side technologies such as bindings. Bindings can thus use double-curly `{{ syntax }}` without collision from Angular 2 component double-curly `{{ syntax }}`.

The important part being `Angular 2 does not compile/process bindings in index.html`. So, in order to do what you want, you will have to move `ng-content` to a child component.

Answer (score 13):

Turns out it's possible, if you intend to provide textual content. If you want Angular components, it's possible with the right HTML element (noscript). A little hacky, one might say. The trick is using a `<noscript>` element.

HTML template:

```
<noscript id="appContent">
   <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
   <a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>
</noscript>
<script>
    var mainTemplate = document.getElementById('appContent');
    window.mainTemplate = mainTemplate.innerText;
</script>
```

Root component:

```
import {Component, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: 'Header: ' + window.mainTemplate ,
})
export class App {
}

bootstrap(App);
```

Make sure your Angular 2 code comes after the template definition.

*Only applies if you use a `<template>` tag:* The catch is that since recently (http://angularjs.blogspot.com.br/2016/02/angular-2-templates-will-it-parse.html) Angular 2 brings its own parser, templates are case-sensitive. It is not the case for HTML in a browser environment. It means the browser may not keep the case in attributes and elements on this template hack.

**UPDATE**: I had a `<template>` element in the original solution. A `<noscript>` is much better as shouldn't be any case conversion.