# ng-content in root Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The page shows basic markup, comforting message and loading indicator.

```
<html>
...
<body app>
...page layout and loading stuff...
</body>

</html>
```

And root component is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'body[app]',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
App {}
```

A plunker that demonstrates the problem is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/knL07UGiXBqeJahT5Uqo?p=preview).

After SPA initialization it is supposed to bootstrap `body` element and compile components while saving existing basic layout.

However, root component just ignores `ng-content`.

This leads to two options. The initial layout should be dumped and shown only after bootstrapping. Or it should be duplicated in both root component template and HTML document (likely with server-side templating). None of them looks good enough.

`body` contains sensitive markup that cannot be just wrapped into child component to overcome this limitation. I intend to use Angular Universal to provide SPA with neat static preview, but not at this stage.

It looks like it is a known problem but I'm unable to find a workable solution.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The supposed duplicate contains outdated answers which I don't find satisfying. Things have changed, and I was hoping that there is a better answer, not without a reason.

Comment: What do you mean with "not without a reason". I'm not aware of any changes regarding to this question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Despite the title (possibly inaccurate), this isn't RTM question and not a duplicate, the question is not why this happens but how to achieve the desired behaviour. I'm not happy with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35444285/3731501) solution and would like to know if there are more idiomatic approaches that possibly involve hacking core A2 providers and don't require Universal. Dupe question has already got a fair answer. This one has not.

Comment: It's still the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568808/angular2-root-component-with-ng-content even if you want a different anseer but it's not that important.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks. I can remove the part that mentions `ng-content` entirely if this helps to get the gist of it, though this would make the context of the question less obvious.

Answer (score 5):

The link below has been given the status `fixed by ivy`. Ivy is a milestone for angular v7.0.

---

Transcludes are not supported on the root element, you can't pass anything to it because index.html isn't part of angular. If you can't embed the html within another component then I wouldn't expect it to work with `ng-content` either.

From https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#issuecomment-207993202

> Components only work as components when referenced in the template of
>   another component, yet they are expected to be used outside of this
>   which causes confusion

Answer (score 0):

Using `<ng-content>` in root component planned to be implemented.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4946