# Angular2 component - render html from the index page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angular2-template

Is it possible to render html which is inside `app-nav` tag already, rather then providing it in `templateUrl`?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  // commented out - templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent {
  title: string = 'This is my title';
}
```

Html that is already on the html page.

```
<app-nav>
  nav works! {{ title }}
</app-nav>
```

If I uncomment the `templateUrl` then app-nav will be replaced by nav-component.html page, but I dont want that. I have dynamic html and I want to render that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use embedded view with `ngTemplateOutlet` projection. Wrap your content within `<app-nav>` tags in `<template>`. Than in your `NavComponent` find this `TemplateRef` with `ContentChild` and insert this templateRef into component's template passing context that contains your title variable to it. Something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent {
  title: string = 'This is my title';

  @ContentChild('defaultTemplate') defaultTemplate = null // get templateRef
}
```

In nav.component.html create template outlet with relative template context

```
<template [ngOutletContext]="{ title: title }" [ngTemplateOutlet]="defaultTemplate"></template>

....other component content....
```

And then in place of component use:

```
<app-nav>
  <template #defaultTemplate let-title="title">
    nav works! {{ title }}
  </template>
</app-nav>
```

**UPD:**

Here is a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/MwvhQ8d6Zbm4zidrlGK2?p=preview) with example

in `app/some.component.ts` there is a `ngTemplateOutlet` projection from `app/app.component.ts` `template`

**UPD:**

Ok, there is a way to get initial content from index.html into the component. You can use `APP_INITIALIZER` function that will be executed when an application is initialized.

Here is the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/MwvhQ8d6Zbm4zidrlGK2?p=preview)

1. See `app/root-template.initializer.ts`
2. In `app/app.component.ts` I just replace relevant property with initial content. This is a bit hacky way and should be done by replacing template in `ComponentMetadata` which is obtained with Reflect.getMetadata:

   ```
   const annotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', NavComponent)
   const meta = annotations.find(annotation => annotation instanceof ComponentMetadata)

   meta.template = meta.template.replace(
     '{{ someVarInTemplate }}',
     'initialContentInIndex'
   )
   ```

This way the component template will have initial index content and it will be parsed by angular.
More about Reflect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465214/access-meta-annotation-inside-class-typescript)

Comment: didn't work, it was replaced by `nav.component.html` content

Comment: Well, it should work. Perhaps there is a mistake somewhere. I've updated my answer with a plunk demoing how that should be implemented

Comment: Actually I wanted to put that `nav works {{ title }}` inside `<my-app>Loading...</my-app>` my-app tag.. basically that `app-nav` is root component and not sub component.  Is it still possible?

Comment: I don't think so. You can find explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568808/angular2-root-component-with-ng-content#answer-32574733

Comment: I came up with a solution. It's not complete but it works. To make it fully right  I just need some more investigation but perhaps it's enough for you:)

Comment: first of all, thank you for looking into this. Have you worked more on this? I really would like the template to render as it renders in angualr2, rendering like following, will just not work well for little big components. `"this.initialStuff = AppComponent.rootTemplate.replace('{{ title }}', this.title) // this is a hacky way..."` really prefer to have this automated (as angular2 does it)

Answer (score 0):

@Yaroslav, expanding on your solution:

1. Looks like a transclusion (in Angular 1 terms), so in Angular 2 you can use ng-content on the inner component.

   ```
   <div class="my-component">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
   </div>
   ```
2. To get interpolation working on outer transcluded markup, give the element an id and prefix the interpolated content with it.

   ```
   <my-component #comp>
     This is my transcluded content! ++{{comp.title}}++
   </my-component>
   ```
3. Don't try to transclude from **index.html**, it's not an angular component, so it doesn't seem to work as the outer component. If you use app.component as the outer and another my.component as inner, it works.

Here's a fork of your plunkr with the changes. [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fgCAhhHeaOW6L8yTsxsf?p=preview)

For reference, I used Todd Motto's excellent article on angular 2 transclusion: [ref here](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content).
The angular guide only vaguely refers to ng-content (with a link that 404's), so I wonder if it's disappearing. May be superseded by **ngComponentOutlet** [ref here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgComponentOutlet-directive.html)