# Angular 2 Ng-Content and it seems not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to use Ng-Content and it seems not working. The full code is here in plunker [Full code](http://plnkr.co/edit/QW7uLSIx7AjvOp7rUBAv?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div>
        Title:
        <ng-content select=".my-component-title"></ng-content>
      </div>
      <div>
        Content:
        <ng-content select=".my-component-content"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

I have updated the plunker code and now the ng-content is not at the root component. But still its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ng-content>` on the root component is not supported.

`<ng-content>` only transcludes elements and components defined in an Angular2 component.

See also [Angular2 root component with <ng-content>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568808/angular2-root-component-with-ng-content)

Comment: I have update the plunker code and now ng-content is not in the root

Comment: But there is also nothing matching the selectors. It's still entirely unclear what your question is about. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hi. I used `<ng-content>` in root in a project and it works, but now I can't do that in a new project and I can't understand where's the problem. Could you help me? This is the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388854/why-is-angular-transclusion-ignored-in-app-root