# Render content between the component tags

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

When a component is rendered, content inside it is ignored, for example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div>{{title}}</div>',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Using it like:

```
<app-root>Ignored content</app-root>
```

Renders:

```
<div>app works!</div>
```

But looking at PrimeNg dialog, they use components like this:

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display">
    <p-header>
        Header content here
    </p-header>
    Content
    <p-footer>
        Footer content here
   </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

As `Header content here`, `Content` and `Footer content here` are inside the component, why are not they getting ignored and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Add `<ng-content></ng-content>` to the component's template where the content should be projected:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  template: '<div>{{title}}</div>
             <br>
             <ng-content></ng-content>',
})
export class DemoComponent {
  title = 'Works!';
}
```

Content to be projected:

```
<app-demo>This is projected content!</app-demo>
```

The output will be:

```
Works!
This is projected content!
```

Here is a great article about Angular Content Projection (Angular 1 Transclusion): [Transclusion in Angular 2 with ng-content](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content)

Comment: any idea how to access the content inside <ng-content> inside the component ?

Comment: @Shilpa You can use '@ContentChild' and '@ContentChildren' to access projected content.

Comment: I am surprised that this answer got so many upvotes as it shows non-working example. By looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568808/angular2-root-component-with-ng-content) you will see that `ng-content` cannot be used inside `index.html`, where `app-root` is first initialized.

Comment: @YuriyKravetsso for example, I upvoted it as it explains how to show content added between components tags, I do not care of example