# Angular 5 - content between component tags

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I made a custom modal for my Angular 5 app, but I want to be able to edit the content in it.

As example I have the following bit of code

```
<app-modal> <p>Some Text!</p> </app-modal>
```

I want the modal to take the `<p>` tag and put it like this:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="card">

    <p>Some Text!</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

So I can easily reuse the modal component and easily use it everywhere I need it. But I couldn't find if/how this works anywhere. If it's not possible, then I wonder what the next best way is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Render content between the component tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355236/angular-2-render-content-between-the-component-tags)

Comment: I don't get the reason why to use `<p>` tag if you can use `<app-modal>` itself anywhere.

Comment: @ochs.tobi I think this could work! I'm going to try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355236/angular-2-render-content-between-the-component-tags) from [ochs-tobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8381155/ochs-tobi), I found the thing I was looking for.

Just add `<ng-content></ng-content>` wherever you need in the component to be able to get the content within the tags of the component.

Comment: you can find the best solution for the same here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360691/how-to-make-a-modal-reusable-in-angular-2/56559002#56559002