# Angular 6 - Cannot create angular components under custom HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, angular-components

I have two angular components whose respective templates are called *home.component.html* and *information-icon.html*.

I am using custom HTML elements, so when I define my custom elements together only in one template, for example in *home.component.html*, the template shows correctly elements defined:

```
<!-- home.component.html-->
<sh-access-bar label="Access bar">
   <sh-button icon="example.png"></sh-button>
</sh-access-bar>
```

Nevertheless, I need two separate components to my purpose, so If I defined both templates like this, the component doesn't render correctly:

First component:

```
<!-- home.component.html-->
<sh-access-bar label="Access bar">
   <app-information-icon></app-information-icon> <!--Component selector-->
</sh-access-bar>
```

Second component:

```
<!--information-icon.component.html-->
<sh-button icon="example.png"></sh-button>
```

Are there any way in Angular to render both components correctly?
Are there any properly way to create custom tags dynamically as a component?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: try `ng-content ` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355236/angular-2-render-content-between-the-component-tags#answer-42355321

Comment: @Programmer thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't help me to solve this issue