# How To Put HTMLElement Inside Component Like Angular Material does

Tags: angular

In AngularMaterial, I saw code like this.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

There are `<input>` element inside `<mat-form-field>` component.

Usually, when I wrote element inside component, It wil be ignored.

How can I do this.

Comment: Did you import the forms component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355236/render-content-between-the-component-tags This is the one example which you finding for. In this you can properly find example of how to use <ng-content></ng-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `<ng-content></ng-content>` to slot your element.

https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b