# How to display block component inside another one?

Tags: angular

I have a custom component called cat used in the system like that:

```
<cat>
   <b>This is a cat</b>
</cat>
```

Inside the cat component template i would like to show data nested inside the use of cat component above (in this example bolded "This is a cat" text.

What is a syntax for this? Something like (cat.ts):

```
{{showblockComponentContentSomethingLikeYeld}}
```

Comment: You need to explain a bit more

Comment: What's a **block** component?

Comment: Is the cat alive or dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cat component is a child component, the parent component that has the child "Cat" component should be as you mentioned:

```
`<app-child><h1>Hello World</h1></app-child>`
```

While here's the trick, the angular way is to use ng-container.
In the child "Cat" component:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Hope it helps and good luck

Comment: Thanks! It is precisely what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<cat>
  <blockcomponent *databinding attributes classes*></blockcomponent>
</cat>
```

Where cat & blockcomponent are two seperate components.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than nesting content between the selectors, you can pass it to your `cat` component and then render it in the `cat.html`.  Like this:

```
<cat [myContent]="This is a cat"></cat>
```

then have something like this in your component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
[...]
@Component({
  [...],
  selector: 'cat'
})
export class MyCatComponent {

@Input() myContent: string;

[...]

}
```

and in cat.html:

```
{{ myContent }}
```

or, if you're passing HTML markup

```
<div [innerHTML]="{{ myContent }}"></div>
```

or, try this previously answered option:
[Render content between the component tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355236/render-content-between-the-component-tags)